# how to context menu open with clicking enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

i have a grid on that context menu, i want open the context menu by pressing enter not use right click or shift +f10 . how can i do?

```js
orgContextMenuItems['Organizationdetails'] = {
  name: nmc.platform.strings.OrganizationDetails,
  icon: "cut",
  callback: function(key, options) {
    try {
      editOrganization();
    } catch (error) {
      NMCApp.showNMCExceptionWindow('Jquery Error:' + error);
    }
  },
  disabled: function() {
    try {
      if (selectedOrganization != null)
        return false;
      else
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
      NMCApp.showNMCExceptionWindow('Jquery Error:' + error);
    }
  }
};

searchOrgGrid.contextMenu({
  selector: 'div',
  items: orgContextMenuItems
});
```